# how I can use Mongo with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, mongo

Please, how I can use Mongo with Magento? And does Mongogento (https://github.com/Smile-SA/mongogento) work with Magento community edition?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Mongo and Magento but I have heard that https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo is a good module.

From my understanding this module will work with Community and will allow you to build your own extension/module based on a Mongo database.